# How do you replace all the related entities in a Spring Boot app using Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a `User` entity that has many `Address` entities.

The `Address` has the relationship defined like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private User user;
```

The `User` has the relationship defined like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
private List<Address> addresses;
```

Now the API is defined such that the list of addresses is part of the User API and needs to be updated when the user is updated. I'm trying to remove the entire list of addresses from DB and replace it with the new list. How do I do that?

This is what I tried, but this results in the creation of new entries in the `Address` table:

```
User user = userRepository.findById(id).get();

// ...... some other code ......

List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

List<AddressRequestDto> addressRequestDtos = UserRequestDto.getUser();
for (AdressRequestDto addressRequestDto : addressRequestDtos) {
  Address address = addressRequestDto.to();
  address.setUser(user);
  addresses.add(address);
}

user.setAddresses(addresses);


user = userRepository.save(user);
```

Comment: is it actual code or modified code ? part after - `// ...... some other code ......`

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: Existing address entities are not loaded to persistance context because of FetchType.LAZY, so JPA doesnt do anything about them. If you changed FetchType to EAGER on list of addresses and remove explicitly these addresses, it should work..

Comment: @PiotrCierpich, could you put it as an answer with some more details? I'm not sure where the `FetchType.LAZY` would be need to be added. And how would I remove the addresses explicitly?

Comment: @PiotrCierpich, yes! although I did not use the `clear()` method. It worked without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you want to delete child address entities, so I'd do the following:

```
@Entity
public class User {
...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Address> addresses;
```

OrphanRemoval makes sure addresses are removed when no relation from users exists. Eager fetch makes addresses being fetched together with users. Update should have explicit removal of addresses:

```
User u = userRepository.findById(id).get();
u.getAddresses().clear(); // explicitly clear existing addresses
... // other updates
u.getAddresses().add(a1); // ad new addresses
userRepository.save(u);
```